# Exporting to PDF using ArcPy of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf

I have a weird issue in exporting the layout to PDF
My code is really simple and I have tried in ArcGIS Python IDLE but I have came across the problem.

My Code and error is :

**Code:**

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
Layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
Layout.exportToPDF(r"C:\1.pdf")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 975, in exportToPDF
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.exportToPDF(*gp_fixargs((out_pdf, resolution, image_quality, compress_vector_graphics, image_compression, embed_fonts, layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality, clip_to_elements), True)))
OSError: C\1.pdf
```

Comment: What happens when you try to save it to a directory instead of the root of the C:\ drive and give it a name that starts with a letter, i.e. C:\temp\a1.pdf

Comment: I have tried and it worked. Actually, it was part of my script tools and the problem was I was referring to save pdf to project path instead of project folder path. but as curiosity why could not we able to save in C drive.

Comment: If you’re using CURRENT you need to run the code from within Pro.  You can’t run it from outside the app, in Idle.  CURRENT doesn’t exist there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a filename that starts with a numeral like this:

```
Layout.exportToPDF(r"C:\1.pdf")
```

gives that `OSError` and using one that does not like this:

```
Layout.exportToPDF(r"C:\temp\test1.pdf")
```

does not give the error, then it suggests to me that you may not be using supported file naming conventions for ArcGIS Pro.  If I can find a link to where these are documented I will add it into this answer.

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be a Pro problem. Its almost certainly a domain policy setting within the users organization. I'm at a company where I cannot create `c:\foo.txt` using notepad.